# win ver not define

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am using vc++ in windows 7. I want to change default version from #define 0x00600 to #define 0x00601. But again give message winver not define and cant open.

Answer (score 2):

Create file file `targetver.h` and include it in your `stdafx.h`. The `targetver.h` looks like this:

```
#pragma once

#ifndef WINVER  
#define WINVER 0x0700  
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT 
#define _WIN32_WINNT
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINDOWS 
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0510 
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_IE                    
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0700     
#endif
```